# Concurrency vs parallelism in Golang

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing, atomic, compare-and-swap

I'm trying to implement double compare and swap (and maybe MWCAS) both in Golang and Rust, and since no CPU supports this instruction I need to find a way using what the language offers me.

Let's take this code:

```
func HttpServer(parallelism int) {

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(parallelism)

    called := 0

 http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
     time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
     called++
     fmt.Fprint(w, called)
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
```

In general it's wrong, but if we call `HttpServer(1)` it works as expected: let's say I call the endpoint 1000 times, I will get 1000 different values of `called`, from 1 to 1001, in less than 3 seconds. This is because if we execute with `parallelism = 1` the go runtime will execute the handler after `time.sleep` as an atomic block of code, while waiting for all the other handlers at once.

Using this trick I can implement DCAS and MWCAS with little effort, without using atomics (5x slower) or mutexes (25x slower)

My questions are:

- Is anything wrong with this code? Am I missing some details? Why the race detector still detect races even with parallelism set to 1? (but the results are correct, so it doesn't seem to affect output)
- Is there a way to set `runtime.GOMAXPROCS` per goroutine and its descendants? so for example one goroutine and its children will execute with parallelism 1, while another will execute with parallelism 10. For now the only way I see is to launch multiple processes and then communicate with IPC.

Comment: You should take a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69508104/5291015

Comment: The scheduler can yield anywhere and anytime, it could be in the middle of Printf, it could be between reading and storing the value of count — there are no guarantees about what happens outside of the memory model and language spec.

Comment: sorry @JimB that's not true, at least in practice. Check my comments below for references. The only corner case is cgo.

Comment: What is done in practice to implement a specification has no bearing on what is actually specified. Yield points were very coarse early on, and the compiler has been making finer grained control decisions throughout the development of the standard go implementation. (Note we’re also assuming the gc implementation here, other implementations could work quite differently)

Comment: @JimB what I might concede is that, while this code works today, it might breaks at any time in the future, and that it would be maybe better done in Rust, where you write your own coroutine scheduler. 
Even though the go memory ref seems to guarantee that this pattern should be safe.

Comment: There’s very little difference between a broken program which might work for an indeterminate amount of time and a broken program which does not work at all.

Comment: "Is there a way to set runtime.GOMAXPROCS per goroutine and its descendants" makes no sense. Goroutines don't have descendent relationships for one thing, and for another every goroutine has a parallelism of 1 on its own; `GOMAXPROCS` is only meaningful across all goroutines being managed by the scheduler.

Comment: @Adrian In rust is possible. You can create an executor which is multi threaded or single threaded, and you can dynamically change the parallelism during execution. 
For each coroutine you launch you can decide wherever it inherits the scope of the parent, or if it exist in a different thread pool.

Comment: @Mascarpone I'm not sure how that's relevant here - the question is about Go not Rust, right?

Comment: One of the features of Go is that such stuff is _not_ possible, forcing everybody to write the same proper code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is anything wrong with this code?

Yes, it's racy.

> Is there a way to set runtime.GOMAXPROCS per goroutine and its descendants?

No.

Comment: Looks racy, but with parallelism set to 1 it works correctly.

Comment: It’s still a race, though it may or may not be triggered based on the current compiler and runtime implementation

Comment: My understanding is that the race is never triggered. The go scheduler cannot yield after time.sleep of before fmt.Printf, so if you are single threaded that code is atomic. I wrote some code to detect race conditions, and even on large tries on multiple machine it never happens.

Comment: Racy code is buggy. Dead simple. It doesn't matter the slightest whether "the race is never triggered" or not.

Comment: @Mascarpone, Even if there is no concurrent memory access, goroutines are also not guaranteed to see any of the other modifications from other goroutines without explicit synchronization.

Comment: thanks @JimB, that's a valid point. Where could I read more about this?

Comment: As usual: https://go.dev/ref/mem

Comment: "The go scheduler cannot yield after time.sleep or before fmt.Printf." How do you figure? That's not written anywhere in the language spec.

Comment: thanks @Volker , your link seems to confirm what I'm saying: `Some compiler optimizations that would be valid in single-threaded programs are not valid in all Go programs. In particular, a compiler must not introduce writes that do not exist in the original program, it must not allow a single read to observe multiple values, and it must not allow a single write to write multiple values.`
The compiler introduces `runtime.Gosched()` calls only in certain places, so memory operations are safe for concurrent single threaded access.

Comment: @Peter you can read about it in many places. E.g.: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24543 `Currently, Go currently uses compiler-inserted cooperative preemption points in function prologues. `
https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/08/scheduling-in-go-part2.html `The Go scheduler requires well-defined user-space events that occur at safe points in the code to context-switch from. These events and safe points manifest themselves within function calls`
In the links there is an enumeration of the places where the scheduler might yield.

Comment: These are all implementation details that can change at any time. And golang/go is just one implementation. There are also gollvm, gccgo, GopherJS, wasmer-go, and probably more.